# $A(X\times Y)\cong A(X)\otimes A(Y)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

I'm looking to understand a previous post. It was a while ago so I thought I would repost. Here is the post  [Tensor product of 2 coordinate rings](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/114938/tensor-product-of-2-coordinate-rings). My questions come from the Dylan's answer.

I was able to show that the map was well defined and onto. I'm stuck on the injection. If $\{f_{i}\}$ and $\{g_{j}\}$ generate $K[V]$ and $K[W]$ as a k-algebra shouldn't there be elements of this form $f_{i}^{2}\otimes g_{j}$ as well when we try to generate $k[V]\otimes k[W]$.

If $\{f_{i}\}$ and $\{g_{j}\}$ generate $k[V]$ and $k[W]$ as vector spaces, then I can see why we do without the products. But we won't get a finite generating set for $k[V]$ as a vector space.

Any ideas would be very much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $\{f_i\}$ and $\{g_j\}$ generate, respectively, $k[V]$ and $k[W]$ as $k$-algebra's, then $\{ f_i \otimes g_j \}$ does not (necessarily) generate $k[V] \otimes k[W]$ as $k$-algebra. Think for instance of $k[x] \otimes k[y]$, which is not generated, as a $k$-algebra, by $x \otimes y$.

As you already mentioned, if $\{f_i\}$ and $\{g_j\}$ generate $k[V]$ and $k[W]$ as $k$-vectorspaces, then $\{f_i \otimes f_j\}$ generates $k[V] \otimes k[W]$ as a $k$-vectorspace. Dylan's answer to the question you link to refers to generating sets (bases, even) for $k$-vectorspaces.

What does, however, generate $k[V] \otimes k[W]$ as a $k$-algebra is $\{ f_i \otimes 1, 1 \otimes g_j \}$. That's enough to make all the $f_i^n \otimes g_j^m$, which already generate $k[V] \otimes k[W]$ as a $k$-vectorspace.

Comment: That is as I thought. So is there someway to fix his argument for injection or should I scrap it and start a new?

Comment: You mean the argument by Dylan for injectivity at the other question? That seems to work - exactly because he looks at the tensor product as a $k$-vectorspace.