# Tensor product of coordinate rings corresponds to pullback

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, tensor-products

[Here](http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/AG.pdf#page=106) in Milne's notes on algebraic geometry, he proves that if $k$ is an algebraically closed field, and $A$ and $B$ are reduced finitely generated $k$ algebras, then $A \otimes_k B$ is reduced. (This is good for proving that the product of affine algebraic sets has coordinate ring the tensor product over $k$ of the coordinate rings of the algebraic sets.)

Is there a way to tweak Milne's proof to show that if $R$, $A$, and $B$ are finitely generated $k$ algebras, all reduced, then $A \otimes_R B$ is reduced? (This would be good for proving that the coordinate ring of $Y \times_X Z$ is $A \otimes_R B$.)

Here's my attempt at the proof of the pullback-tensor correspondence. It seems that I really do need to show that $A \otimes_R B$ is reduced to make my version of the proof work. (Correct me if I'm wrong.) https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYBIg.png

These questions are similar, but don't quite hit the nail on the head: [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/114938/tensor-product-of-2-coordinate-rings), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/300917/tensor-product-of-domains-is-a-domain), [3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/152056/is-fibre-product-of-varieties-irreducible-integral), [4](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/9436/reduced-%E2%8A%97-reduced-reduced-what-about-connected). In particular, #4 deals with much more involved ways of showing these results.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$A\otimes_R B$ is not always reduced. In fact, this is good, because it may be used to see intersection multiplicities. Here is an example.

Let $R=k[X,Y]$ be the coordinate ring of the plane. Let $A=k[X,Y]/(Y)$ be the coordinate ring of the line $Y=0$ in this plane, and $B=k[X,Y]/(Y-X^2)$ be the coordinate ring of the parabola $Y=X^2$. Then $A\otimes_R B=k[X,Y]/(Y,Y-X^2)\simeq k[X]/(X^2)$. This is not reduced and correspond to the fact that this two plane curves intersect with multiplicity 2.

Edit : By the way, tensor products corresponds to pull-back in the category of affine schemes. Schemes are more involved way of dealing with rings to see stuff like multiplicities. The pull-back for varieties corresponds to first take tensor products, then take the reduced ring (mod out by the nilpotents). Indeed, note that points corresponds to algebra morphisms $A\otimes_R B\rightarrow k$, but since $k$ is reduced, it also corresponds to algebra morphisms $(A\otimes_R B)_{red}\rightarrow k$.

Comment: Very clarifying, thank you. Especially the last sentence was something I'm glad you pointed out!