Why can't we prove that $k[V \times W] \simeq k[V] \otimes_k k[W]$ this way?
I was asked to prove the statement in the question above as an exercise. As soon as I have done that I checked my proof with the proof from Shafarevich's book "Basic algebraic geometry". His proof of injectivity of an arrow
$$
k[V] \otimes_k k[W] \to k[V \times W]
$$
$$
f\otimes g \mapsto fg
$$
is the same as in the answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/122321/763588. And I understand it. In Shafarevich's proof we work with basis. But I think we can prove injectivity easier.
Let $\sum_i c_if_ig_i = 0$, so $\forall x\in V, y \in W: \sum_i c_if_i(x)g_i(y) = 0$. Finally, $$
\sum_i c_if_i(x)\otimes g_i(y) = 1\otimes(\sum_i c_if_i(x)\otimes g_i(y)) = 1\otimes0 =0 \quad \forall x\in V,y\in W.
$$
So $\sum_i c_if_i\otimes g_i = 0$. Is my proof of injectivity correct? Does it have mistake? In my opinion, this proof is correct, I only use properties of tensor product, but maybe I don't see that I've made stupid mistake. Surjectivity is obvious and I use the same argument as Shafarevich.
Thanks!

It is not correct. You need to prove $\sum_i c_i (f_i \otimes g_i)=0$ in $k[V] \otimes k[W]$. This is a priori not the same as proving $\sum_i c_i (f_i(x) \otimes f_i(x)) = 0$ in $k \otimes k = k$ for all $x,y$ (which is what you do). Actually, the result shows a posteriori that it is sufficient, but yeah your proof is circular for this reason. As a beginner, I would also advise you to always pay close attention in which tensor product you are working in, since the notation $\otimes$ is a bit ambiguous.

So I've found what I don't understand: why I can't simply check that my element is zero in every point and then claim that it is zero function? Is my mistake that I talk about elements of tensor product as a functions but I can't say where they are defined? (Of course it is natural define it on direct product, but we can think about another algebraic sets?)

Yes, exactly. You assume essentially what needs to be proven. Tensor product of functions $\neq$ function on product (a priori). The tensor product works for arbitrary, abstract modules, so anything about function spaces need to be proven first. By the way, you can also study a related but more difficult question: If $X,Y$ are topological spaces and $C(X)$, $C(Y)$ are the rings of real-valued continuous functions, is the evident ring map $C(X) \otimes_{\mathbb{R}} C(Y) \to C(X \times Y)$ injective?

Thanks a lot for your answer and question about continues maps!
